# How to use retention annotation with RetentionPolicy in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

I want to use `java.lang.annotation.Retention` for my annotation class, but it report it is deprecated and use `kotlin.annotation.Retention` instead.

```
// import java.lang.annotation.Retention        when I comment this line

@MustBeDocumented
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)      // it report RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME type mismatch error
annotation class ActivityScoped
```

Just remove `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` because of it is already set in default.